# Safe casting in python

Tags: python, casting

How to do safe cast in python

In c# I can safe cast by keyword as, e.g.:

```
string word="15";
var x=word as int32// here I get 15

string word="fifteen";
var x=word as int32// here I get null
```

Has python something similar to this?

Comment: Note that Python doesn't actually *have* casting; this is just passing the value to the other type's constructor.

Comment: Use C# for C# programming. In Python you want to use exceptions, not nulls.

Comment: That isn't even valid in C#.  It's a compile error.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Think not, but you may implement your own:

```
def safe_cast(val, to_type, default=None):
    try:
        return to_type(val)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return default

safe_cast('tst', int) # will return None
safe_cast('tst', int, 0) # will return 0
```

Comment: I feel like this isn't the most efficient option if you expect exceptions to happen frequently.

Comment: I'd add `TypeError` exceptions as well

Answer (score 51):

I do realize that this is an old post, but this might be helpful to some one.

```py
x = int(word) if word.isdigit() else None
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! You may want to edit your answer in order to format your code. For instance, 4 spaces before your code line will mark it as a code. You may want to read the [formating help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to better understand how to properly markdown your questions and answers. You will get a better chance with them if they are well formatted.

Comment: I like this very clear one-line solution.

There's also `.isdecimal()` and `.isnumeric()`. If you want to test for _just_ ordinary digits then `.isdecimal()` is strictest: It will consider numbers with 0 to 9 valid, but would return False for sub- or superscript numbers like `¹²³`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789392/str-isdecimal-and-str-isdigit-difference-example) has a good discussion of the differences, esp. the answer from 'Henry Keiter'.

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: Great way with ternary operator!

Comment: This should be avoided since using `word = '⓪③⑧'` will result in raising error with `int()` failing. I guess using `isdecimal()` instead of `isdigit()` would make this work as expected.

Answer (score 6):

I believe, you've heard about "***pythonic***" way to do things. 
So, safe casting would actually rely on "Ask forgiveness, not permission" rule.

```
s = 'abc'
try:
    val = float(s) # or int 
    # here goes the code that relies on val
except ValueError:
    # here goes the code that handles failed parsing
    # ...
```

Comment: Hacks to get around a flaw in the language need to be hidden in a function like Artsiom's answer. Anybody who spreads exception handling throughout their code base saying its the "Pythonic" way will not stay employed long.

Answer (score 3):

There is something similar:

```
>>> word="15"
>>> x=int(word)
>>> x
15


>>> word="fifteen"
>>> x=int(word)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'fifteen'


>>> try: 
...     x=int(word)
... except ValueError:
...     x=None
... 
>>> x is None
True
```

Comment: Note that you should never use bare except clauses, so you want to use `except ValueError:` in this case, otherwise it'll catch typos, syntax errors, etc.

Comment: that's right, I wanted to focus on the point only, but probably it's better to show that too.

Answer (score -4):

Casting has sense only for a variable (= chunk of memory whose content can change)

There are no variables whose content can change, in Python. There are only objects, that aren't contained in something: they have *per se* existence. Then, the type of an object can't change, AFAIK.

Then, casting has no sense in Python. That's my believing and opinion. Correct me if I am wrong, please.

.

As casting has no sense in Python, there is no sense to try to answer to this question.

The question reveals some miscomprehension of the fundamentals of Python and you will gain more profit obtaining answers after having explained what led you thinking that you need to cast something

Comment: When working in the context of the internet query parameters are represented as strings. In order to make those parameters useful to your internal modules you often have to cast '15' to 15. That's just one possible case.

Comment: Ok, it's not casting is a conversion. The question make sense anyway. There's no need to be so negative: -1

Comment: Why casting has no sense in Python? I think casting might be used to implement Polymorphism with minimal duplicated code... IIRC... AFAIK...

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`