# str.isdecimal() and str.isdigit() difference example

Tags: python, python-3.x

Reading python docs I have come to .isdecimal() and .isdigit() string functions and i'm not finding literature too clear on their usable distinction.  Could someone supply me with code examples of where these two functions differentiate please.

Similar behaviour:

```
>>> str.isdecimal('1')
True
>>> str.isdigit('1')
True

>>> str.isdecimal('1.0')
False
>>> str.isdigit('1.0')
False

>>> str.isdecimal('1/2')
False
>>> str.isdigit('1/2')
False
```

Comment: `str.isdigit('\u00b2')` vs. `str.isdecimal('\u00b2')` would be an example.

Comment: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-May/624356.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between str.isdigit, isnumeric and isdecimal in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891070/whats-the-difference-between-str-isdigit-isnumeric-and-isdecimal-in-python)

Comment: @adam Broken link. https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-May/774712.html

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There *are* differences, but they're somewhat rare<sup>*</sup>. It mainly crops up with various unicode characters, such as <sup>`2`</sup>:

```
>>> c = '\u00B2'
>>> c.isdecimal()
False
>>> c.isdigit()
True
```

You can also go further down the careful-unicode-distinction rabbit hole with the `isnumeric` method:

```
>>> c = '\u00BD' # ½
>>> c.isdecimal()
False
>>> c.isdigit()
False
>>> c.isnumeric()
True
```

---

<sup>*</sup>At least, I've never encountered production code that needs to distinguish between strings that contain different types of these exceptional situations, but surely use cases exist somewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What is a _common_ example where `isdecimal` and `isdigit` differ? I have never used `isdecimal` and most of the numbers I use would return `True` for both.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I can only find 128 characters of 1114112 for which `c.isdigit() != c.isdecimal()`.  That's pretty rare.

Comment: @DSM: Okay, if you are going to put it that way.. Any reason why you deleted your answer, btw?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: When you find one, you found a whole group; U+00B2, U+00B3, U+00B9 is more of an exception; most of the matches come in continuous code point groups.

Comment: @DSM: there is another way to look at it: ~20% of "isdigit()" characters are not "isdecimal()" (`(678-550)/678`—`unicodedata.unidata_version == '8.0.0'`) i.e., given a decimal, there is 20% chance that it is a decimal but in typographic context (`c.isdigit() and not c.isdecimal()`)--it is not that rare. Also, there are only 1514 characters with a numeric value.

Answer (score 28):

Lets see some examples:

> **str.isdecimal()**  (Only Decimal Numbers)

Is 34 a decimal number? --> Yes

```
print("34".isdecimal())  #True
```

Is superscript 2 a decimal number? --> No

```
print("\u00B2")
print("\u00B2".isdecimal())  #False
```

> **str.isdigit()** (Decimals, Subscripts, Superscripts)

Is 34 a digit? --> Yes

```
print("34".isdigit()) #True
```

Is superscript 2 a digit? --> Yes

```
print("\u00B2")
print("\u00B2".isdigit()) #True
```

> **str.isnumeric()** (Decimals, Subscripts, Superscripts, Vulgar Fractions, Roman Numerals, Currency Numerators)

Is 34 a numeric number? --> Yes

```
print("34".isnumeric()) #True
```

Is superscript 2 a numeric number? --> Yes

```
print("\u00B2")
print("\u00B2".isnumeric()) #True
```

Is Vulgar Fraction one Quarter numeric number? -->Yes

```
print("\u00BC")
print("\u00BC".isnumeric()) #True
```

Answer (score 16):

If you doubt, my advice is to code, look at results, and then draw conclusions.

### A code

```
In [115]: import itertools
     ...: 
     ...: line = '-' * 37
     ...: print(line)
     ...: print("|    №   | isdigit | isdecimal | chr")
     ...: print(line)
     ...: for number in itertools.chain(range(1000), range(4969, 4978), range(8304, 11000)):
     ...:     char = chr(number)
     ...:     if (char.isdigit() or char.isdecimal()):
     ...:         print('| {0:>6} | {1:^7} | {2:^9} | {3:3} '.format(
     ...:             number,
     ...:             '+' if char.isdigit() else '-',
     ...:             '+' if char.isdecimal() else '-',
     ...:             char
     ...:         )
     ...:     )
     ...:
```

### Look at results

```
-------------------------------------
|    №   | isdigit | isdecimal | chr
-------------------------------------
|     48 |    +    |     +     | 0   
|     49 |    +    |     +     | 1   
|     50 |    +    |     +     | 2   
|     51 |    +    |     +     | 3   
|     52 |    +    |     +     | 4   
|     53 |    +    |     +     | 5   
|     54 |    +    |     +     | 6   
|     55 |    +    |     +     | 7   
|     56 |    +    |     +     | 8   
|     57 |    +    |     +     | 9   
|    178 |    +    |     -     | ²   
|    179 |    +    |     -     | ³   
|    185 |    +    |     -     | ¹   
|   4969 |    +    |     -     | ፩   
|   4970 |    +    |     -     | ፪   
|   4971 |    +    |     -     | ፫   
|   4972 |    +    |     -     | ፬   
|   4973 |    +    |     -     | ፭   
|   4974 |    +    |     -     | ፮   
|   4975 |    +    |     -     | ፯   
|   4976 |    +    |     -     | ፰   
|   4977 |    +    |     -     | ፱   
|   8304 |    +    |     -     | ⁰   
|   8308 |    +    |     -     | ⁴   
|   8309 |    +    |     -     | ⁵   
|   8310 |    +    |     -     | ⁶   
|   8311 |    +    |     -     | ⁷   
|   8312 |    +    |     -     | ⁸   
|   8313 |    +    |     -     | ⁹   
|   8320 |    +    |     -     | ₀   
|   8321 |    +    |     -     | ₁   
|   8322 |    +    |     -     | ₂   
|   8323 |    +    |     -     | ₃   
|   8324 |    +    |     -     | ₄   
|   8325 |    +    |     -     | ₅   
|   8326 |    +    |     -     | ₆   
|   8327 |    +    |     -     | ₇   
|   8328 |    +    |     -     | ₈   
|   8329 |    +    |     -     | ₉   
|   9312 |    +    |     -     | ①   
|   9313 |    +    |     -     | ②   
|   9314 |    +    |     -     | ③   
|   9315 |    +    |     -     | ④   
|   9316 |    +    |     -     | ⑤   
|   9317 |    +    |     -     | ⑥   
|   9318 |    +    |     -     | ⑦   
|   9319 |    +    |     -     | ⑧   
|   9320 |    +    |     -     | ⑨   
|   9332 |    +    |     -     | ⑴   
|   9333 |    +    |     -     | ⑵   
|   9334 |    +    |     -     | ⑶   
|   9335 |    +    |     -     | ⑷   
|   9336 |    +    |     -     | ⑸   
|   9337 |    +    |     -     | ⑹   
|   9338 |    +    |     -     | ⑺   
|   9339 |    +    |     -     | ⑻   
|   9340 |    +    |     -     | ⑼   
|   9352 |    +    |     -     | ⒈   
|   9353 |    +    |     -     | ⒉   
|   9354 |    +    |     -     | ⒊   
|   9355 |    +    |     -     | ⒋   
|   9356 |    +    |     -     | ⒌   
|   9357 |    +    |     -     | ⒍   
|   9358 |    +    |     -     | ⒎   
|   9359 |    +    |     -     | ⒏   
|   9360 |    +    |     -     | ⒐   
|   9450 |    +    |     -     | ⓪   
|   9461 |    +    |     -     | ⓵   
|   9462 |    +    |     -     | ⓶   
|   9463 |    +    |     -     | ⓷   
|   9464 |    +    |     -     | ⓸   
|   9465 |    +    |     -     | ⓹   
|   9466 |    +    |     -     | ⓺   
|   9467 |    +    |     -     | ⓻   
|   9468 |    +    |     -     | ⓼   
|   9469 |    +    |     -     | ⓽   
|   9471 |    +    |     -     | ⓿   
|  10102 |    +    |     -     | ❶   
|  10103 |    +    |     -     | ❷   
|  10104 |    +    |     -     | ❸   
|  10105 |    +    |     -     | ❹   
|  10106 |    +    |     -     | ❺   
|  10107 |    +    |     -     | ❻   
|  10108 |    +    |     -     | ❼   
|  10109 |    +    |     -     | ❽   
|  10110 |    +    |     -     | ❾   
|  10112 |    +    |     -     | ➀   
|  10113 |    +    |     -     | ➁   
|  10114 |    +    |     -     | ➂   
|  10115 |    +    |     -     | ➃   
|  10116 |    +    |     -     | ➄   
|  10117 |    +    |     -     | ➅   
|  10118 |    +    |     -     | ➆   
|  10119 |    +    |     -     | ➇   
|  10120 |    +    |     -     | ➈   
|  10122 |    +    |     -     | ➊   
|  10123 |    +    |     -     | ➋   
|  10124 |    +    |     -     | ➌   
|  10125 |    +    |     -     | ➍   
|  10126 |    +    |     -     | ➎   
|  10127 |    +    |     -     | ➏   
|  10128 |    +    |     -     | ➐   
|  10129 |    +    |     -     | ➑   
|  10130 |    +    |     -     | ➒
```

### Draw conclusions

As you can see, the main difference between the function `str.isdecimal()` and `str.isdigit()` is that the function `str.isdecimal()` returns `True` only for numbers from 0 to 9, while the function `str.isdigit()` returns `True` for some other Unicode-supported chars as well.

Comment: The conclusion lacks an important caveat: isdecimal() returns True for decimal numbers in *various character systems*. Example: "๑".isdecimal() returns True (Unicode Character 'THAI DIGIT ONE' (U+0E51)).

Comment: It is a great and simple idea to just try it :-). But unfortunately the presented result is not true. If you do not narrow the character set to few small ranges and use instead `range(65536)` then you will see that `isdecimal` return `True` for many other characters too.

Answer (score 3):

Completing the answer from [PADYMKO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6003870/padymko), we can add the other function of interest and extend the code

### Code

```
import itertools
line = '-' * 49
print(line)
print("|    №   | isdigit | isdecimal | isnumeric | chr |")
print(line)
for number in itertools.chain(range(1000), range(4969, 4978), range(8304, 11000)):
    char = chr(number)
    if (char.isdigit() or char.isdecimal() or char.isnumeric()):
        print('| {0:>6} | {1:^7} | {2:^9} | {3:^9} | {4:3} |'.format(
            number,
            '+' if char.isdigit() else '-',
            '+' if char.isdecimal() else '-',
            '+' if char.isnumeric() else '-',
            char
        )
    )
```

### And the results

```
-------------------------------------------------
|    №   | isdigit | isdecimal | isnumeric | chr |
-------------------------------------------------
|     48 |    +    |     +     |     +     | 0   |
|     49 |    +    |     +     |     +     | 1   |
|     50 |    +    |     +     |     +     | 2   |
|     51 |    +    |     +     |     +     | 3   |
|     52 |    +    |     +     |     +     | 4   |
|     53 |    +    |     +     |     +     | 5   |
|     54 |    +    |     +     |     +     | 6   |
|     55 |    +    |     +     |     +     | 7   |
|     56 |    +    |     +     |     +     | 8   |
|     57 |    +    |     +     |     +     | 9   |
|    178 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ²   |
|    179 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ³   |
|    185 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ¹   |
|    188 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ¼   |
|    189 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ½   |
|    190 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ¾   |
|   4969 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ፩   |
|   4970 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ፪   |
|   4971 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ፫   |
|   4972 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ፬   |
|   4973 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ፭   |
|   4974 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ፮   |
|   4975 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ፯   |
|   4976 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ፰  |
|   4977 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ፱   |
|   8304 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⁰   |
|   8308 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⁴   |
|   8309 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⁵   |
|   8310 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⁶   |
|   8311 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⁷   |
|   8312 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⁸   |
|   8313 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⁹   |
|   8320 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ₀   |
|   8321 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ₁   |
|   8322 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ₂   |
|   8323 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ₃   |
|   8324 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ₄   |
|   8325 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ₅   |
|   8326 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ₆   |
|   8327 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ₇   |
|   8328 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ₈   |
|   8329 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ₉   |
|   8528 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅐   |
|   8529 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅑   |
|   8530 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅒   |
|   8531 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅓   |
|   8532 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅔   |
|   8533 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅕   |
|   8534 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅖   |
|   8535 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅗   |
|   8536 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅘   |
|   8537 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅙   |
|   8538 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅚   |
|   8539 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅛   |
|   8540 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅜   |
|   8541 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅝   |
|   8542 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅞   |
|   8543 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅟   |
|   8544 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅰ   |
|   8545 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅱ   |
|   8546 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅲ   |
|   8547 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅳ   |
|   8548 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅴ   |
|   8549 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅵ   |
|   8550 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅶ   |
|   8551 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅷ   |
|   8552 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅸ   |
|   8553 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅹ   |
|   8554 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅺ   |
|   8555 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅻ   |
|   8556 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅼ   |
|   8557 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅽ   |
|   8558 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅾ   |
|   8559 |    -    |     -     |     +     | Ⅿ   |
|   8560 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅰ   |
|   8561 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅱ   |
|   8562 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅲ   |
|   8563 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅳ   |
|   8564 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅴ   |
|   8565 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅵ   |
|   8566 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅶ   |
|   8567 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅷ   |
|   8568 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅸ   |
|   8569 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅹ   |
|   8570 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅺ   |
|   8571 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅻ   |
|   8572 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅼ   |
|   8573 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅽ   |
|   8574 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅾ   |
|   8575 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⅿ   |
|   8576 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ↀ   |
|   8577 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ↁ   |
|   8578 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ↂ   |
|   8581 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ↅ   |
|   8582 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ↆ   |
|   8583 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ↇ   |
|   8584 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ↈ   |
|   8585 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ↉   |
|   9312 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ①   |
|   9313 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ②   |
|   9314 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ③   |
|   9315 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ④   |
|   9316 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⑤   |
|   9317 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⑥   |
|   9318 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⑦   |
|   9319 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⑧   |
|   9320 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⑨   |
|   9321 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⑩   |
|   9322 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⑪   |
|   9323 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⑫   |
|   9324 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⑬   |
|   9325 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⑭   |
|   9326 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⑮   |
|   9327 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⑯   |
|   9328 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⑰   |
|   9329 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⑱   |
|   9330 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⑲   |
|   9331 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⑳   |
|   9332 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⑴   |
|   9333 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⑵   |
|   9334 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⑶   |
|   9335 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⑷   |
|   9336 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⑸   |
|   9337 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⑹   |
|   9338 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⑺   |
|   9339 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⑻   |
|   9340 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⑼   |
|   9341 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⑽   |
|   9342 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⑾   |
|   9343 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⑿   |
|   9344 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒀   |
|   9345 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒁   |
|   9346 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒂   |
|   9347 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒃   |
|   9348 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒄   |
|   9349 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒅   |
|   9350 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒆   |
|   9351 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒇   |
|   9352 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⒈   |
|   9353 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⒉   |
|   9354 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⒊   |
|   9355 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⒋   |
|   9356 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⒌   |
|   9357 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⒍   |
|   9358 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⒎   |
|   9359 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⒏   |
|   9360 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⒐   |
|   9361 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒑   |
|   9362 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒒   |
|   9363 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒓   |
|   9364 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒔   |
|   9365 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒕   |
|   9366 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒖   |
|   9367 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒗   |
|   9368 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒘   |
|   9369 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒙   |
|   9370 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒚   |
|   9371 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⒛   |
|   9450 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⓪   |
|   9451 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⓫   |
|   9452 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⓬   |
|   9453 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⓭   |
|   9454 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⓮   |
|   9455 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⓯   |
|   9456 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⓰   |
|   9457 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⓱   |
|   9458 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⓲   |
|   9459 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⓳   |
|   9460 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⓴   |
|   9461 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⓵   |
|   9462 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⓶   |
|   9463 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⓷   |
|   9464 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⓸   |
|   9465 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⓹   |
|   9466 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⓺   |
|   9467 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⓻   |
|   9468 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⓼   |
|   9469 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⓽   |
|   9470 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ⓾   |
|   9471 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ⓿   |
|  10102 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ❶   |
|  10103 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ❷   |
|  10104 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ❸   |
|  10105 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ❹   |
|  10106 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ❺   |
|  10107 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ❻   |
|  10108 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ❼   |
|  10109 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ❽   |
|  10110 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ❾   |
|  10111 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ❿   |
|  10112 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➀   |
|  10113 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➁   |
|  10114 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➂   |
|  10115 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➃   |
|  10116 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➄   |
|  10117 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➅   |
|  10118 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➆   |
|  10119 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➇   |
|  10120 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➈   |
|  10121 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ➉   |
|  10122 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➊   |
|  10123 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➋   |
|  10124 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➌   |
|  10125 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➍   |
|  10126 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➎   |
|  10127 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➏   |
|  10128 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➐   |
|  10129 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➑   |
|  10130 |    +    |     -     |     +     | ➒   |
|  10131 |    -    |     -     |     +     | ➓   |
```

PS: I am sorry for the wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

isdigit()

- 0123456789 only
- the value is safe to be parsed to an integer.
- used for validating text & file input data
- can be called from bytearray and bytes as well.
- not used for formatting output text

isdecimal()

- value should be "displayed as a number"

  - eg: don't hyphenate across a line break.
- not used for validating numerical input [ie int("₂") raises ValueError]
- can be used to inform "natural text sorting" algorithms.
- can be used for validating chemical formulas: "H₂O" and "H2O"

Comment: Actually this is backwards regarding validation. For example ² and ② both return True for isdigit() but False for isdecimal(), and neither can be parsed as an int. All unicode characters with isdecimal() == True do successfully parse as int.

Comment: In fact isdecimal() is a strict subset of isdigit(), and seems to be the exact set that Python allows for number parsing.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Tg2.png)

examples of isdigit
a = "123"

a.isdigit()

true

a = "1.234"

a.isdigit()

false

a ="2²"

a.isdigit()

b = "3₄"

b.isdigit()

The roman numerals, currency numerators and fractions
(usually written using unicode) are considered numeric
characters but not digits. The  isdigit() returns  False if
the string contains these characters

Roman Numerals : Ⅰ, Ⅱ ,Ⅺ
currency numerators : $,₹,€,£
fractions : ½,⅔,¼

c = "Ⅺ"

c.isdigit()

false

d = "₹"

d.isdigit()

false

e = "½"

e.isdigit()

false

some examples of isdecimal ()

a = "123"

a.isdecimal()

true
b = "3₄"

b.isdecimal()

c = "Ⅺ"

c.isdecimal()

false
d = "₹"

d.isdecimal()

false
e = "½"

e.isdecimal()

false

The superscript and subscripts are considered digit
characters but not decimals. If the string contains these
characters (usually written using unicode),  isdecimal()
returns  False.
Similarly, roman numerals, currency numerators and
fractions are considered numeric numbers (usually written
using unicode) but not decimals. The  isdecimal() also
returns  False in this case.

source link : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/isdecimal
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/isdigit

if i am wrong then please correct me
just a new learner

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).