# isnumeric & isdecimal not behaving as expected

Tags: python, string, python-3.4

In python strings have a method `isnumeric` and `isdigit`.

I was under the (wrong) impression that `isnumeric` and `isdecimal` would return `True` for strings such as `123.45` and false otherwise. I'm running the following version of python:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Jan  7 2015, 11:54:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
```

And I found that `isnumeric` and `isdecimal` return true if all characters in the string are integers, but false if a `'.'` (dot) is present. What causes this behaviour? Shouldn't `'123.45'.isnumeric()` return `True`?

```
>>> mystr_a = '123.45'
>>> mystr_b = '123'
>>> 
>>> mystr_a.isnumeric()
False
>>> mystr_a.isdecimal()
False
>>> mystr_b.isnumeric()
True
>>> mystr_b.isdecimal()
```

Comment: Did you check [`isnumeric`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) and [`isdecimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal) docs? This is the documented behaviour.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789392/isdecimal-and-isdigit-difference-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As defined in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric), `isnumeric` returns `True` if all characters within the string are numeric, otherwise `False`. A dot is not considered to be numeric.