# ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python

So... I have this primitive calculator that runs fine on my cellphone, but when I try to run it on Windows 10 I get...

> ValueError: could not convert string to float

I don't know what the problem is, I've tried using `raw_input` but it doesn't work ether. Please keep in mind I'm green and am not aware of most methods for getting around a problem like this

```
num1 = float(input ()) #take a float and store it
chars = input () #take a string          and store it
num2 = float(input ())
```

Comment: you should not have characters in your `input` and don't use `input` use `raw_input` instead.

Comment: I don't intend to input characters. My code does not allow me to input even a float it simply reads the line, skips it and gives me a ValueError . I'll post the whole program once I get on my laptop.

Comment: Please include what inputs are failing. (What examples you're trying, if "everything".)

Comment: Give me a few minutes

Comment: I'm trying to send the whole program but it does not fit into the comments section.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702382/touble-running-this-program

Answer (score 2):

your code only convert string that are integers like in below statement

```
num1 = float(input ()) #take a float and store it ex 13
print num1 # output 13.0
```

if you provide `13` as a input it will give the output as `13.0`
but if you provide `SOMEONEE` as input it will give `ValueError`

And it is same with the case of `raw_input()` but the difference is that by default `raw_input()` takes input as a string and `input()` takes input as what is provided to the function

Comment: I am aware that inputting strings gives a ValueError. My program does not even allow me to input onto the variable, it simply skips that command. BUT I have the exact same code running a calculator on my phone and it works but it won't work on my desktop

Comment: Please edit the question and explain in brief what you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702382/touble-running-this-program

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because in some cases 'input' contains non-numerical characters. Python is smart and when a string only contains numbers, it can be converted from string to float. When the string contains non-numerical characters, it is not possible for Python to convert it to a float.

You could fix this a few ways:

1. Find out why and when there are non-numerical characters in your input and then fix it.
2. Check if input contains numbers only with: [isdecimal()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdecimal.htm)
3. Use a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

**isdecimal() example:**

```
my_input = raw_input()
if my_input.isdecimal():
    print("Ok, go ahead its all numbers")
```

**UPDATE:**
Two-Bit-Alchemist had some great advice in the comments, so I put it in my answer.

Comment: The `isdigit` method is less than great here because (1.) anything with a decimal point will fail this test (alternative: `isdecimal`) and (2.) the OP needs numbers to calculate with later so may as well go ahead and cast, being prepared to catch `ValueError` (your option 3).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist thanks for the pointers! I edited my answer :)

Comment: Your heading still says "isdigit" example. I tried to fix it but your latest edit you accidentally rolled it back ;)

Comment: FIXED! :) Thanks again

Comment: Anything with a decimal point will also fail `isdecimal()`. [The difference between `isdigit` and `isdecimal`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789392/) is apparently just some unicode characters.

Comment: @glibdud Wow, that is maddeningly poorly documented. "All characters that can be used to form a decimal-radix number" -- except the most common and obvious ASCII period? Good grief.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702382/touble-running-this-program