# ValueError when trying to convert strings to floating point

Tags: python

I'm having troubles running this program.
It tells me I have a

> ValueError: could not convert string to float

The problem is though, that it just skips my input commands and jumps to

```
print("Invalid Response")
```

This program works fine on my cellphone but not on my windows 10 laptop.

Any help? Try running it and let me know if it works for you.

```
def calc():        #The function performing calculation. 
    if chars == "+":
        result = num1 + num2
        print (result)
        return result
    elif chars == "-":
        result = num1 - num2
        print(result) 
        return result 
    elif chars == "*":
        result = num1 * num2
        print(result)
        return result 
    elif chars == "/":
        result = float(num1) / float(num2)
        print(result)
        return result 
    else:
        print("Invalid or unsupported operation")

cont = ""  
def contin():
        result = calc()
        print("Operate? y/n: ")
        cont = input()  
if cont == "y": 
        print(result)           # output is:                  ought to be:
        chars = input()                   #result                     result
        contin_num = float(input()) 
        calc(contin_num)        #result                     operate y/n
        print(result, chars, contin_num)     

elif cont == "n":
        result = 0
        print(result)
else:
        print ("Invalid response.")


num1 = float(input ()) 
chars = input () 
num2 = float(input ()) 
result = 0       

while num1 > 0 or num2 > 0: 
    calc()
    contin()
    break
if num1 == 0 and num2 == 0:
    print("Zero or undefined.")
```

Comment: Your indentation is bad: your `elif`'s have a different indentation than the `if`, and they also have less indentation than the rest of the code in the function. Fix the indentation then try again.

Comment: those are just adjustments I made because Stack Exchange insisted I have a four space indentation. It is not this way on my original program all if's and elif's are indented properly. Make the correction and try running it.

Comment: No, it is *your* responsibility to post code that corresponds to what you want to run. I do not know where you want your function `calc()` to end so it would be difficult for me to do the corrections. The usual way to post code is to copy-and-paste from your text file, highlight the code with your mouse or keyboard, then click the "code sample" icon (which looks like a pair of braces) in the question editor. This will easily add the four spaces to each line.

Comment: aye aye cap, give me a sec. I might have to send a link since the code is too long for a comment.

Comment: Why did you create a duplicate question instead of updating [the previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700249/)?

Comment: hey I'm new here! cut me some slack I'm focused on my code not the ins and outs of stackoverflow

Comment: hey I made the corrections what do you think?

Comment: Making multiple questions splits answers/comments into multiple places. Since there are no answers on this one yet, I'd recommend editing the changes into your previous question and deleting this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is the desired code. I changed a little bit some indentations are wrong in case of contin() function and some logic. Please refer to this if I am wrong in some place do tell me. Thank you

```
def calc(num1,chars,num2):        #The function performing calculation. 
    if chars == "+":
        result = num1 + num2
        print (result)
        return result
    elif chars == "-":
        result = num1 - num2
        print(result) 
        return result 
    elif chars == "*":
        result = num1 * num2
        print(result)
        return result 
    elif chars == "/":
        result = float(num1) / float(num2)
        print(result)
        return result 
    else:
        print("Invalid or unsupported operation")

cont = ""  
def contin(res):
        num1 = res
        print("Operate? y/n: ")
        cont = raw_input()  
    if cont == "y": 
            print(num1)           # output is:                  ought to be:
            chars = raw_input()                   #result                     result
            num2 = float(input()) 
            num1=calc(num1,chars,num2)        #result                     operate y/n
            print num1     

    elif cont == "n":
            result = 0
            print(result)
    else:
            print ("Invalid response.")


num1 = float(input ()) 
chars = raw_input () 
num2 = float(input ()) 
result = 0       

while num1 > 0 or num2 > 0: 
    res = calc(num1,chars,num2)
    contin(res)
    break
if num1 == 0 and num2 == 0:
    print("Zero or undefined.")
```