# Extract digits from position 5th to 7th in a given list if they contain no letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm unable to get this working for the desired result. I also want to separate the items in the list that do not have digits in position from 5th to 7th.

List:

```
HLJ3007A7S
SKC4491U7K
NAS1782P3K
MK217TRG
RRS38W23KS
```

Output I am getting:

```
007
491
782
7TR
8W2
```

The result I want:

```
007
491
782
```

This is the for loop I could code:

```
for d in optionList:
    validCodes.append(d[4:7])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
option_list = [
    "HLJ3007A7S",
    "SKC4491U7K",
    "NAS1782P3K",
    "MK217TRG",
    "RRS38W23KS"]

has_digits = [i for i in option_list if i[4:7].isdigit()]
```

Comment: What is better/worse when using isdigit compared to isdecimal as suggested in the other answer?

Comment: Technically isdecimal is a bit more accurate, but it doesn't really matter in this case. It has to do mostly with Unicode handling. As an example, both of them would show an Arabic 0 as a decimal, but since you're not dealing with Arabic or any Unicode whatsoever the difference is irrelevant.

Comment: You can read this if you wish https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789392/str-isdecimal-and-str-isdigit-difference-example

Answer (score 0):

str has a convenient method called *isdecimal* which you could utilise as follows:

```
data = ["HLJ3007A7S", "SKC4491U7K", "NAS1782P3K", "MK217TRG", "RRS38W23KS"]
new_list = [s for s in data if not s[4:7].isdecimal()]
print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['MK217TRG', 'RRS38W23KS']
```

Comment: What is better/worse when using isdecimal compared to isdigit as suggested in the other answer?

Comment: isdecimal tests strictly for digits 0-9 whereas isdigit returns True for superscript numbers such as ² as well as numbers in the 0-9 range